# Click on the List view Item

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android ,  I have list view in which i have  One Image view and three Text view . All i want to perform Click event on text view only. I tried using "OnItemClicklistener" of list-view , but at first click of list , whole row get click-able, which i don't need it . i want to click Text view on very first click of the List . I did listing from this link example "http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/".

Any kind of help is appreciated . 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can set onclick listener for every textview and pass unique id for all, by doing this you can achieve..

Comment: how to do that , could tell me some information . Thank you.

Comment: Follow the @Nishant Shah answer's steps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of SimpleArrayAdapter use custom adapter. [Check this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Check example of point **2. Adapter implementations**

And inside the adapter implement your textView.setOnClickListener(..)

Comment: Hey Nishant , thank you for reply , i did according to your response for my question . But that didnt work either.

Answer (score 3):

simple use the lazyadapter class and add onclick event on it

Answer (score 0):

you should create onclicklistener for Textview for which that you want click event in your custom adapter class.